# Arrange UILabels in UIstackView Dynamically

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uistackview

I am adding labels as subview to UIstackview using arrangedSubView property.

what happens is that if I keep Stackview axis horizontal, 
I get one horizontal strip of UILabels

```
label1 label2 label3 label4.....
```

if I keep it vertical, I get a vertical strip of UILabels
like below

```
label1
label2
label3
and so on
```

But what I am trying to achieve is this

```
label1, label2(if it fits) otherwise take it below
label3, label4
label5 and so on
```

presently  my code is this

```
 uiLabel1.numberOfLines = 1
            uiLabel1.backgroundColor = THEMECOLOR
            uiLabel1.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleCaption1)
            uiLabel1.textColor = topicColor
            uiLabel1.layer.cornerRadius = (CGFloat)(5.0)
            uiLabel1.layer.masksToBounds = true
            uiLabel1.sizeToFit()
            uiLabel1.userInteractionEnabled = true           


            self.dynamicStackView.addArrangedSubview(uiLabel1)
```

Comment: This sounds like a UICollectionView might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with Maple. Sounds like a job for a collection view. Otherwise you'll need to write code that builds a stack view of stack views dynamically, which would be a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Flow Layout of the `UICollectionView` is what you need. Have a look at the link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW1)